# MS Excel: How to "flatten" a hyperlink created from a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Say my sheet is like so:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║   A   ║   B   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ itemA ║ 10001 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Now, this number in column B is actually a suffix with which links can be created, for example:
`http://www.mycrazysite.beer/store/10001`

So, I have created a third column with the links by doing: 
`=HYPERLINK("http://www.mycrazysite.beer/store/"&B1,B1)`

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║   A   ║   B   ║   C   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ itemA ║ 10001 ║ 10001 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

(Imagine column C is a hyperlink that refers to the full URL of the item on my site and the "friendly_name" is the text in column B)

However, now I have a bit of redundancy and would like to do away with column B and keep column C, without of course breaking the links created by the function.

- I tried copy-pasting as "text" but that just removed all the hyperlink goodness and pasted the "friendly_name"

Any functionality or tricks to achieve that (on office365)?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this;

1. Write the formula so that the text is displayed in the column C.

- Formula `="HYPERLINK(""http://www.mycrazysite.beer/store/"&B1&""","""&B1&""")"`
- Result displayed `HYPERLINK("http://www.mycrazysite.beer/store/10001","10001")`

2. Fill formula down.
3. Then Copy & Paste Values so you have each hyperlink text without any formulas.
4. Use the Find & Replace feature to change `"HYPER"` to `"=HYPER"`.

This should turn each line of text back into a hyperlink formula. Keep in mind tho this is a one time tick, if you intend on adding additional lines then you would need to repeat the process.